# Socket client not connection

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to use the socket client, but all the attempts were unsuccessful, I did the same in the documentation and it didn't work.

```
        import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

    export function testUsingWithNodeHTTPServer () {
      console.log('=============SOCKET===============')
      const socket = io('http://localhost:8080', {
        path:" /chat/socket",
        extraHeaders: {
          session_id: "452c6c87-30ad-4ed7-bfc5-467dd5633d1d"
        }
      })
      socket.on("connect", () => {
        console.log('Client connected.');
      })

    }
```

Version:

```
"socket.io-client": "4.3.2",
```

Comment: Apart from using socket client you also need to use socket server. Do you use socket server ?

Comment: yes, i'm using it in another api

Comment: make sure your `path` and `port` are correct

Comment: Yes, I use them on Postman and it works normal